# Is forcing older IE into quirks mode bad?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I built a web app using some technologies that do not work well for IE 8/9. The app functions well in Chrome and Firefox and mostly okay in Standard IE 10 but breaks down in IE 8/9 standard. However, if I switch over to quirks mode for IE 8/9 in the developer console, it works perfectly for some reason. Is there a danger to trying to force quirks mode for older IE?

Comment: You should really fix your issues instead. What errors are you getting?

Comment: We're using angularjs and theres just a ton of issues from ajax caching to pushstate to errors I don't really even know about. We've been trying to fix errors per their documentation but a lot of stuff still fails. Another odd thing is once I put it on quirks mode once, even if I switch back & completely clear cache, everything works perfectly. I had to restart my computer to reproduce my earlier errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would say that it's definitely not optimal and you should be trying to fix the errors that prevents you to run in standard mode, however if you are unable to do it and it's the only way to go, I do not see how a working application running in quirks mode could be worse than a failing application in standard mode.

Comment: Hmm any idea why it would work in quirks but not standard? I was under the impression quirks mode was meant to support old websites...

Comment: @wlingke It is, Quirks mode is like IE5, but without knowing explicitely what errors you are getting I have no idea what else you could do.

Comment: Decided to bite the bullet and take the time to fix things properly. Sigh, if only IE did not exist.